# Contact form issues - clicking on any field refreshes the page and clears all entries

Tags: html, forms, contact-form

Trying to setup a basic contact form, but I can't figure out why the whole page keeps refreshing & clearing fields whenever any of the form fields are clicked. (Using an HMLT5up template + Formspree) Any ideas or help is much appreciated!

code snippet attached -- *email address placeholder in snippet

[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myNT9.png)

[util.js screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jw1Ek.png)

Comment: you have some script in your page probably... html code only can't refresh the page.

Comment: Yes, makes sense. Thank you for the reply. I have very little js knowledge, but the template that I'm using has a few .js files. This one looks like it could be the culprit, but I don't know enough to know what to edit to fix the issue. Seems to me that it's not refreshing the page, but is resetting the form and scroll position. Any ideas? Thanks again! (adding screenshot of the util.js code to the original post as I can't get it to paste as text in this comment)

Comment: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/#fullpagejs

try this if this helps you please mark bro))